# How to get turn by turn details real-time to my app

Tags: android, google-maps, arduino, arduino-uno

I'm doing a arduino project for my end year project.I'm making a smart glove for bike riders which can notify phone calls,Health tracking,Geo tracking and Navigation.
I want to know is there any method I can get details about turn by turn navigation into my app.

i.e :if google navigation said "turn left" get that details and display in my app.

P.S:There is a product called Sneakair by easy jet shoes that auto vibrate when turn is arrived.

If this is impossible tell me another idea that can embed to my project it would appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be aware about certain restrictions regarding Google Maps APIs.
The Terms of service, paragraph 10.4 c says:

> No navigation. You will not use the Service or Content for or in connection with (a) real-time navigation or route guidance; or (b) automatic or autonomous vehicle control.

https://developers.google.com/maps/terms#10-license-restrictions

So, you cannot use Maps API for real-time applications.

Comment: Sir thank you for the answer. If there any suitable change I can done to my project tell it would appreciated.

Comment: You can study other map (and navigation) providers like [Mapzen](https://mapzen.com/products/turn-by-turn/), [Mapbox](https://www.mapbox.com/blog/mobile-navigation/) and [Skobbler](http://developer.skobbler.com/).